# Java Jframe not opening on export

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

Im trying to show some images in a Runnable Jar, When I run it in eclipse it works fine,  but when I export it, it just does not load, the files are in the jar but It just wont run, Ive been trying to crack down as to why, I originally thought it was the image but I completely removed it from the Project and it still wont run, I think its got something to do with resource loading, but I honestly don't have a clue, Here is my code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Window2");
        frame.setLocation(600, 300);
        frame.setSize(140, 125);
        Dimension minSize = new Dimension(800, 600);
        Dimension maxSize = new Dimension(800, 600);
        frame.setMinimumSize(minSize);
        frame.setMinimumSize(maxSize);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(784, 561);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class
                .getResource("/res/BlueSpace.jpg")));
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 794, 493);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Install Modpack");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out
                        .println("Developer - The Modpack has began Installation!");

                frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame1.pack();
                frame1.setLocation(600, 300);
                frame1.setSize(140, 125);
                Dimension minSize = new Dimension(800, 600);
                Dimension maxSize = new Dimension(800, 600);
                frame1.setMinimumSize(minSize);
                frame1.setMinimumSize(maxSize);
                frame1.setResizable(false);
                frame1.setSize(784, 561);
                frame1.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

                JLabel label = new JLabel("");
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class
                        .getResource("/res/BlueSpace.jpg")));
                label.setBounds(0, 0, 794, 493);
                frame1.getContentPane().add(label);

                JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
                progressBar.setBounds(10, 504, 774, 14);
                frame1.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
                progressBar.setValue(25);

                JLabel lblInstallingModpack = new JLabel(
                        "Installing Modpack...");
                lblInstallingModpack.setToolTipText("Modpack Is Installing!");
                lblInstallingModpack
                        .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                lblInstallingModpack.setBounds(300, 529, 150, 14);
                frame1.getContentPane().add(lblInstallingModpack);
                frame1.setVisible(true);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1,
                        "I'm 25% done on the Modpack!", "Not Done Yet...",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);
        btnNewButton.setBounds(531, 504, 253, 56);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        btnNewButton.setEnabled(true);

        JLabel lblWelcomeToThe = new JLabel("Welcome to the Realism Modpack");
        lblWelcomeToThe.setBounds(10, 504, 511, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblWelcomeToThe);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(
                "All Mods owned by there respecive owners");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 546, 511, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnFinish = new JButton("Creators");
        btnFinish.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "Ribenja - ModPack Author", "A List of Great People",
                        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Dave - The 'Enthusiast'",
                        "A List of Great People", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Carl - Ate his hands",
                        "A List of Great People", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "Surf dude - This message was simple",
                        "A List of Great People", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "ThatGuy2000 - A true Hero", "A List of Great People",
                        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "*** - An NSA operative",
                        "A List of Great People", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "Steve - A true Minecrafter", "A List of Great People",
                        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Downloader - you",
                        "A List of Great People", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "I KNOW WHAT YOU DID - A true story teller",
                        "A List of Great People", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

            }

        });
        btnFinish.setEnabled(true);
        btnFinish.setBounds(268, 504, 253, 56);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnFinish);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you run the jar file from the command line are any exceptions thrown? What exactly do you mean by 'it wont run'?

Comment: MDrabic, it runs in the Command line great and works! but why cant I just click it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply i thought i subscribed to emails.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your JAR file doesn't have the resource files packaged, in your case - the image files. Ensure that your JAR has an "res" directory and within it, all the images that your frame needs.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing both images with synthetic variants, the app. appears on-screen here.

### Other Tips

2. Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.
3. Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>1</sup>, along with layout padding & borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556)<sup>2</sup>.
   [image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, solved it the problem was a corrupted java installation.